# Getting null pointer exception in java spring hibernate app

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have class Registration with username email password

I have following function in dao , service classes

```
 public Registration get( Integer id ) {
     logger.debug("Getting person");
        return registrationDAO.findUserByID(id);
     }
```

---

```
@Resource(name="registrationService")
    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    public Registration findUserByID(Integer ID) {

         try {

              Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
              Registration person = (Registration) session.get(Registration.class, ID);
              return person;

         } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    throw new RuntimeException("DAO failed", e);
                }


        }
```

I am using that function in following function

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        // Declare a null Spring User
        UserDetails user = null;
        logger.debug(username);

                //for testing -- i get error here
        Registration regUser = registrationService.get(1);
        logger.debug(regUser);

        try {


            DbUser dbUser = userDAO.searchDatabase(username);
```

I get error when i add this line

```
Registration regUser = registrationService.get(1);
            logger.debug(regUser);
```

Comment: Without showing where you'r creating `registrationService` ... there's no way to tell you.

Comment: i am creating that in customUserdetail Class . i have added that in question

Comment: @Pasha: did you print the value of registrationService , before calling get

Comment: no but as showin in the above code . i have been using like that before as well but i get error on this case

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** For clarified question

```
@Resource
private RegistrationService registrationService;
```

See the tutorial at: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html#bncjl

Comment: i am instantiating via Springbean using @Resource . i have added that in question

Comment: i tried creating service object in old way but still same error

Comment: Have you declared RegistrationService is your spring context?

Comment: yes , i have declared that and that service is running fine in other controllers